# Auto change Image Width/Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using JS/JQuery how can I automatically change an image width/height based on a background DIV tag or window ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="background-div">
 <img src="xxxx.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</div>
```

For dynamic height you should see `jQuery`[.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Using javascript you can change the height dynamically using this

```
var windowHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
document.getElementById("background-div").height = windowHeight + "px";
or
document.getElementById("background-div").style.height = windowHeight + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function both to determine the width of the window and/or div, and also to assign the image's width:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

$('img').width(windowWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the jquery width() and height() methods or using css just specify the following rule.

```
img{ max-width:100%;}
```

Note that, this will set the dimensions of the image based on its parent div dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/background.html 
It's a demo how to display and image with 100% width as a background .

Answer (score 0):

I would use css for this.

**CSS**

```
.bg-Image {
background-image: url();
background-size: contain;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-color: transparent;
width: desiredWidth;
height: desiredHeight;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg-Image"></div>
```

Now you could even use jquery to dynamically change the background-image, width & height of the div.

```
background-size: contain;
```

does the trick.

But it is a css3 property. It will not work in <= ie8.